# Cannot resolve symbol Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: android

This is a development project for a period of time, I opened the project this morning to find my V7 package under the style
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar is red, and some of the other libraries are the same.
But I can compile the normal!!!
I tried
1 Clean Project
2.Rebuild Project
3 invalidate Caches/Restart and so on
Now, I am in IDE, I UI display error, not correct association when referring to me very uncomfortable, to help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Ify.png)

Comment: Post your full `gradle` file.

Comment: I have solved, thank you for your reply...

Comment: @user6246860 Please post solution, so it might useful for other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My colleague Android studio 2.3.0 but my 2.2.3
I used the'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3', he used the'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0', I put the gradle down to 2.2.3 just fine..  Or upgrade your Android studio version to be consistent